# How to pass multiples arguments to thread in c? [Segmentation fault]

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have tried to follow the procedures of several answers/tuturials and I'm still getting segmentation fault on passing multiple arguments to a thread? What am I doing wrong?

struct:

```
struct client_struct {
    int socketId;
    char *message;
};
```

process function:

```
// Handle socket session
void *process(void *client)
{
    client_struct *tmpClient = (client_struct*)client;
    char sendline[BUFFSIZE], recvline[BUFFSIZE];
    printf("can't reach this: %i\n", tmpClient->socketId);
    strncpy(sendline, tmpClient->message, sizeof(sendline)-1);
    sendline[sizeof(sendline)-1] = '\0';
}
```

called from main:

```
int sendMessage(const char *message, int sock)
{
    int result;
    pthread_t process_thread;

    struct client_struct * client;
    client->socketId = sock;
    strcpy(client->message, message);
    printf("segmentation fault here: %s\n", client->message);

    pthread_create(&process_thread, NULL, process, client);
    pthread_detach(process_thread);
}
```

Comment: You have your pointer `client`, but you don't seem to make it *point* anywhere? Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value (that will seem almost random). Dereferencing such a pointer variable leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and is a very common way to get crashes.

Comment: You probably forgot to initialize `client`: `struct client_struct *client = malloc(sizeof *client);`

Comment: Then after the above, you continue to use uninitialized pointers, what will `client->message` point to? What do you think happens when you have that pointer as a destination for a `strcpy` call?

Comment: oh thankz, will try. upvoted! @Someprogrammerdude that comes from arguments, i'm going to edit the question to be more clear, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic problem with undefined behavior when pointer is not initialized.

```
struct client_struct * client;

client = malloc(sizeof(*client)); //Allocate memory for client
client->... = ...; //DO you job
```

By doing `struct client_struct * client;` you are only declaring variable which will (probably at some point) point to data of type `struct client_struct`. Since you don't have your data yet, dereferencing non-initialized pointer leads to undefined behavior.

By using `malloc`, you are setting up valid data for your pointer.

Comment: that line gives me the following
    error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘client_struct*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: Looks like you are not in C but in C++. Use `client = (struct client_struct *)malloc(sizeof(*client));`

Comment: yh, just did that right before you comment, it worked :p sorry to bother you, I already accepted your awnser as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple proxyargs struct can be used also:

```
struct Args
{ int a; float f; char msg[10]; };
...
static void* callback(void* userData)
{
Args* a = (Args*) userData;
/* use args here */
}
...
Args mArgs = {10, 2.0, "message"};
pthread_create(&thread,NULL, callback, (Args*)&mArgs);
enter code here
```